# How do you programmatically run a Sitecore agent using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to run specific agents on demand. When I try to create a new instance of the agent using PowerShell's `New-Object` command it doesn't seem to work right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a few examples I was able to figure out today. I welcome any recommendations on a better way to do this.

Each example loops through the list of agents in the configuration then creates and starts a new job. Using the **Sitecore Configuration Factory**, agents are instantiated and applied as options to a new **Sitecore Job**.

#### CleanupAgent

```powershell
foreach($node in [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetConfigNodes("scheduling/agent") | Where-Object { $_.Type -like "Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent"}) {
    $obj = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::CreateObject($node, $true)
    $name = [Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil]::GetAttribute("type", $node)
    $method = [Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil]::GetAttribute("method", $node)
    $options = New-Object Sitecore.Jobs.JobOptions $name, "", "", $obj, $method
    $options.AtomicExecution = $true
    $options.SiteName = "scheduler"
    [Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager]::Start($options)
}
```

#### CleanupPublishQueue, CleanupEventQueue, CleanupHistory

```powershell
foreach($node in [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetConfigNodes("scheduling/agent") | Where-Object { $_.Type -like "*CleanupPublishQueue*" -or $_.Type -like "*CleanupEventQueue*" -or $_.Type -like "*CleanupHistory*"}) {
    $obj = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::CreateObject($node, $true)
    $name = [Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil]::GetAttribute("type", $node)
    $method = [Sitecore.Xml.XmlUtil]::GetAttribute("method", $node)
    $options = New-Object Sitecore.Jobs.JobOptions $name, "", "", $obj, $method
    $options.AtomicExecution = $true
    $options.SiteName = "website"
    [Sitecore.Jobs.JobManager]::Start($options)
}
```

**Note:** For newer versions of Sitecore (not sure when it changed but experienced an issue on 10.2), the `JobOptions` class name has changed.

Change `Sitecore.Jobs.JobOptions` to `Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJobOptions`.